# How Can I Link back end Go server to front end ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, forms, go, server

How can I enter an input in my App.js file and retrieve is in the go backend server using the FormValue() function?  I don't want to send the values as a JSON object.  The endpoint the form should post to is the PostForm function in Server.go.

The go server should be able to serve the bundled react files without separately sending the input in react to a separate go server and then getting the information back.

Errors:
Currently, when I enter something into the input form, the browser goes to "Cannot POST /api/postform"

Thanks!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>React Starter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script> <!--references the react app -->
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component} from "react";

class App extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            query: '',
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            query: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div className="App">
            <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
            <form action="/api/postform" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="query" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

          </div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

server.go

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/static"
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
  "fmt"
)


func main() {
  // Set the router as the default one shipped with Gin
  router := gin.Default()

  router.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./index.html", true)))

  // Setup route group for the API
  api := router.Group("/api")
  {
    api.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
      c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H {
        "message": "pong",
      })
    })
  }

  // input form should hit this function when it posts
  api.POST("/postform", PostForm)
  router.Run(":5000")
}

// should be able to retrieve the value netered into the form and print it out.
func PostForm(c *gin.Context) {
  c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  q := c.Request.FormValue("query")
  fmt.Println("VALUE IS: ", q)

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? Are you getting any errors? If so maybe include them in the question.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  When I enter something into the input, the browser outputs "Cannot POST /api/postform"

Comment: I may be wrong here but it looks to me, from the webpack config and the server.go file, that you're running two servers that talk past each other. You're serving the react app with a server that's listening on port `:3000` and you're serving the go api on a server that's listening on port `:5000`. When you make a request from `localhost:3000` to `/api/postform` that request is going to be sent to `localhost:3000/api/postform`, not `localhost:5000/api/postform` as you might have believed.

Comment: You either have to serve both the api and the react app from the same server, or send requests from one server **explicitly** to the other, for example try updating the form's action like so `<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/postform" method="POST">`

Answer (score -2):

Generally Front end App Connect to Server with Restful API.